# Select some values from first row in group, while aggregating others

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to combine multiple rows in one table into a single row in another table, to do this we want to have the newest data for most columns, and aggregate data for other columns. We're just taking the top row for now ordering by date, but that unfortunately doesn't give us the correct values on some fields. I would like to do this with a single statement if possible

Example for Current SQL(with string interpolation)

```
INSERT INTO Invoices (InvoiceID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Customer, State, Country, TaxRate, SaleDate, Freight, Subtotal, Tax, Total)
SELECT TOP 1 @InvoiceID, @InvoiceNumber, @InvoiceDate, Customer, State, Country, TaxRate, SaleDate, Freight, Subtotal, Tax, Total FROM Sales 
WHERE SaleNumber in ({SalesNumbers.ToString(",")}) ORDER BY SaleDate DESC
```

In the example we'd want the last three columns (subtotal, tax, total) to be sums of all matching rows in the parent table, but still want all the other values to be selected from the newest data (most recent sale) Is there a away to do this on the insert, or will I need to insert then update the aggregates after?

Comment: "we'd want the last three values to be sums of all matching rows in the parent table, but still want all the other values to be selected from the newest data ".  I have no idea what this means.  Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, simple explanations like what the parent table is would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I gave example SQL - "INSERT INTO Invoices (InvoiceID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Customer, State, Country, TaxRate, SaleDate, Freight, Subtotal, Tax, Total)" The last three values, the last three fields are Subtotal, Tax, Total

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing two types of metadata into one table - a summary and details. Why can't you use two tables, or a table and a view?

Comment: @Alan, We're creating an invoice from multiple sales orders, so we want to sum the info for the financial values, but want the most recent info about the customer, their billing department, etc on the invoice

Comment: Sounds like a violation of a single source of truth to me. Why not compute the values from the underlying data. If you must store the summary, then I suggest you store it in a separate structure and use triggers or middleware to maintain it. Then use multiple recordsets to present the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Since you can't mix aggregates and non aggregates without a group by, I'm splitting the top 1 and the aggregates into subselects within the From clause.

```
INSERT INTO Invoices (InvoiceID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Customer, State, Country, TaxRate, SaleDate, Freight, Subtotal, Tax, Total) 
SELECT [InvoiceID],[InvoiceNumber],[InvoiceDate],[Customer],[State],[Country],[TaxRate],[SaleDate],[Freight]
  ,[Subtotal],[Tax],[Total]
  FROM 
  (SELECT top 1 [InvoiceID],[InvoiceNumber],[InvoiceDate],[Customer],[State],[Country],[TaxRate],[SaleDate],[Freight]
  FROM [Sales]
  where salesnumber in ({SalesNumbers.ToString(",")})
  order by saledate desc) recent_sale,
  (SELECT sum(Subtotal) Subtotal,sum([Tax]) Tax,sum([Total]) Total
  FROM [Sales]
  where salesnumber in ({SalesNumbers.ToString(",")}))  all_sales
```